Using Prism with NPM for Mocking ... I need a different response based on different message id in the path parameter
How the Swagger API File looks :
**
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: Message API
  description: API for returning a message
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /message/{messageid}:
    get:
      summary: Get a message
      description: Retrieve a message
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: messageid
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
      responses:
        200:
          description: Message returned
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string
              examples:
                2:
                  value: "Goodbye from 2, World!"
                  summary: Message 2 response
              examples:
                1:
                  value: "Goodbye from 1, World!"
                  summary: Message 1 response

**
Executing using below command :
prism mock ".\SwaggerSignIn\sample.yml"
Making request using Postman or Insomnia :
http://127.0.0.1:4010/message/2
http://127.0.0.1:4010/message/1
Getting same response in both the cases
"Goodbye from 1, World!"
using Prism Lib for mocking with npm

Thats not the cleanest way to do it, but you can separate it to two different endpoints with hardcoded "messageid" and remove it as a parameter.
paths:
  /message/1
  ...
  /message/2
  ...

Otherwise I think Open API doesn't support dynamics like deciding respponse based on params.
Another way could be to use Prism client to dynamically specify state, expectations, etc. via the code.
